# Invalid column type issue with spring JdbcTemplate

Tags: spring, prepared-statement, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am using spring JdbcTemplate.

```
public int countCallbackResponse(final int empId, final int noOfDay) {

        int callbackCount = getJdbcTemplate().queryForInt(SurveyQuery.COUNT_CALLBACKS,
                new PreparedStatementSetter() {
            @Override
            public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
                ps.setInt(1, empId);
                ps.setInt(2, noOfDay);
            }
        }, Integer.class);
        return callbackCount;
}
```

Error:

```
callback][org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [SELECT COUNT(sr.RESPONSEID) FROM EMPSUR s, EMPSURRES sr WHERE s.IEMPID = sr.IEMPID AND sr.IEMPID=? AND TRUNC(sr.TSCREATED) BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE - (? + s.PRIORITY_DAYS)) AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) AND sr.SSTATUS IN ('SUS1','SUS1')]; SQL state [99999]; error code [17004]; Invalid column type; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type]
```

Comment: The `queryForInt` isn't available in a format that uses a `PreparedStatementSetter`. Currently it tries to pass the instance of the `PreparedStatementSetter` as a query parameter. Either use the plain `query` method (which returns a list) or use the `queryForObject` method without a `PreparedStatement` (The `queryForInt` method is deprecated in newer Spring versions).

Comment: i have to use preparedstatement and queryforobject does'nt support it. can i use getJdbcTemplate().update with prepared statement

Comment: Why do you have to use the `PreparedStatementSetter`? Theer is nothing in the code that suggests you need it.